# Permission denied when running a script with or without sudo in Ubuntu on Windows 10

Tags: command-line, permissions

I'm a total beginner.

I installed Ubuntu on Windows 10. I need to run a script but when I type the command to run it I get this error

```
/bin/bash: bin/yadna : Permission denied.
```

I tried `sudo` but the same error appears.

Comment: You installed Ubuntu on Windows ? Interesting

Comment: are you using a virtual machine ?

Comment: In the Ubuntu systems I have used, when the file has no execute permission, you get `bash: filename: Permission denied` without `sudo`, but when you use `sudo` you get `sudo: filename: command not found` (i.e. a different error, and not the same one as you report, so I am unsure about the cause of the problem) You can check the permissions of the script by, for example, running `ls -l bin/yadna`. Please give further information about your environment (is it WSL?) and show the exact command you are running. It may also help to know what you are trying to achieve by running the script.

Comment: Please don't go and put extra information on your request.

Answer (score 1):

`chmod +x filename` to add execution permission.

You can also type the following into a search engine ;)

`How to execute a file in Linux`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to fix this issue, but you can try a temporary fix by running `sudo -s` to become a superuser, and running the script from there.